# Telegram bot sendVoice() returns always "wrong file identifier"

Tags: telegram-bot

I'm trying to send a voice message from a Telegram BOT, without success.

As a proof of concept I'm trying to do that by using `curl`:

```
#!/bin/bash
TOKEN=$(cat .token)
CHAT=$(cat .chat)
URL="http://server2.mbrt.it:8080/static/foo.ogg"
curl "https://api.telegram.org/bot$TOKEN/sendVoice?chat_id=$CHAT&voice=$URL"
```

But I keep getting:

```
{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: wrong file identifier/HTTP URL specified"}
```

I'm sure that both the token and the chat id are correct, because I'm able to send audio with the `sendAudio` method (sending an mp3 file). The URL I'm using is public, a `wget` from any PC will download the file.

The HTTP headers are also correct AFAIK (note the `Content-Type` header):

```
$ curl -v http://server2.mbrt.it:8080/static/foo.ogg >/dev/null
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.10.3
< Date: Fri, 09 Jun 2017 14:14:11 GMT
< Content-Type: audio/ogg
< Content-Length: 5881
< Last-Modified: Thu, 08 Jun 2017 23:23:21 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< ETag: "5939dc69-16f9"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

My guess was that my encoding was wrong in some way:

```
$ file foo.ogg
foo.ogg: Ogg data, Opus audio,
```

But I tried to encode it either with `ffmpeg`, `opusenc` and `oggenc`. In all cases I get the same error when I send it.

I have no idea of what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it on my own VPS, seems Telegram only accept port 80 for HTTP, and port 443 for HTTPS :(

You can download it, and use `curl -F "voice=@foo.ogg"` to upload it yourself.

Comment: Ah that's weird. Indeed it sends the file now. I'm still not seeing it as voice, but only a file. It looks like the encoding is not correct